# What will be the feasible way to change analyzed to not analyed in elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, migration

I have migrated the data from Mysql to ElasticSearch, then I found that elasticSearch default is analyzed on string. Now I want to change some string fields from analyzed to not-analyzed. which we cannot change directly from elasticsearch. what will be the optimal way to change it without deleting the data? or Should first I backup the elasticSearch data, then create new index with mapping and then migrate from old to new one.

Comment: Backup the data, or export it, create new index, index the exported data.

Comment: Thank you very much  Andrei Stefan, now i reindexed the data. now its working well. By the way in this case, this will be the major disadvantage of ElasticSearch however we can change the index in mysql,mongo easily. Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: It is not so uncommon to change the mapping after the index has been created. For larger indices, indeed, is a more tricky situation. But, if you have the possibility to re-index everything easily, changing the mapping is normal.

Comment: it's true. your are right.

Answer (score 0):

Well , the only option here would be to backup data , create new index with updated mapping and re indexing the entire set of documents to the new one. Elasticsearch produces a great deal of meta data based on the data that you provide on which the search happens. This needs to be regenerated and only way is reindexing.